# How to Use LIKE operator in Informix Function (In parameter passing)

Tags: informix

I am trying to pass an input parameter which is used in a LIKE condition. Why am I unable to get result shown below?

```
CREATE FUNCTION neura_omega_stg.grn_vendor_name_search(vv_vendor_desc Varchar(50))
RETURNING Varchar(15),Varchar(100);

    DEFINE v_vendor_id VARCHAR(15);
    DEFINE v_vendor_desc VARCHAR(100);

    FOREACH cursor1 FOR

    SELECT 
    vendor_id,vendor_desc 
    INTO
    v_vendor_id,v_vendor_desc 
    FROM
    master_vendor_tbl
    WHERE
    vendor_desc like 'vv_vendor_desc'


        RETURN v_vendor_id,v_vendor_desc WITH RESUME;

    END FOREACH;

END FUNCTION
```

---

```
select * from table(grn_vendor_name_search('SURETECH%'));
```

Expected Result:

```
vendor_id vendor_desc
--------- --------------------
MAN1840   SURETECH
MAN1839   SURETECH MEDICAL INC
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the quotes in the WHERE clause SPL variable:

```
... WHERE vendor_desc like 'vv_vendor_desc'
```

should be

```
... WHERE vendor_desc like vv_vendor_desc
```

Comment: I got the expected output. Thanks a Lot.